# Mount network drive

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using linux(ubuntu), there's a linux(fedora) server, that I can log in with ssh, is there any possibility

//server/dir  /mnt/my_mount_dir  cifs  username=loginpassword=11111,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0

As far as I'm concerned, this construction uses SMB as primary tool. Is there any possibility to use NFS or any another approach, because in case of SMB it tends to have permission, symlink collisions.
PS It would be great if you also provide some links. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the remote filesystem on a local folder using sshfs and access files from there.

```
mkdir mountfolder
sshfs username@remotehost:/ mountfolder
```

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also set up nfsd on the server, and mount the usual way:

On the server, create the share in /etc/exports file
On the client, mount the share using /etc/fstab file.

for more details on syntax details and examples, I suggest to dig in the manpages for your systems.